# $httpBackend.whenGET with more than one parameter

Tags: angularjs, httpbackend

I have this URL to match:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/alerts/1121212156/0/4/0').repond(someObject)
```

The problem is that `1121212156` is a tick so it can be different every time. Does someone know how to create a regex to do that?

Answer (score 4):

$httpBackend.whenGET(/\api/alerts/[0-9]+/2/4/0/).
    respond(someObject);

Answer (score 3):

The docs for `$httpBackend.whenGET` say that you can can pass in a regex object in place of a URL.  I just did a quick test on regexpal.com to see if this regex works, and it says it does, although I didn't actually test it through `whenGET`.

```
var urlRegex = /\/api\/alerts\/[\d]+\/0\/4\/0/;
urlRegex.test('/api/alerts/1121212156/0/4/0'); // returns true
```

Hope that helps.